# ¿Como le otorgo permisos de escritura a MagickImage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Cada vez que intento guardar una imagen redimensionada en otra carpeta me marca este error:

```
ImageMagick.MagickBlobErrorException: 'unable to open image 'D:\SISTEMAS\Base 
de datos Editorial\Imagenes': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497'
```

En la parte donde ya solo falta guarar la imagen:

```
using(MagickImage imagen = new MagickImage(imgTrabajador1Loc))
{
   imagen.Resize(80, 80);
   imagen.Write(destino);
}
```

No importa en cual carpeta o ubicacion intente guardarla, igual me dice que no tengo permisos

Comment: pero estas indicando el nombre de un archivo, o solo le asignas una carpeta? lo pregunto porque en el mensaje que muestras no veo ninguna extension de un archivo de imagen como ser .jpg, .png, etc

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el parametro del constructor recibe la dirección de la imagen que voy a alterar, que vendria siendo la variable "imgTrabajador1Loc". Despues lo redimensiona con el método Resize en la parte de imagen.Resize(80,80) y finalmente lo guarda en otra carpeta con el método Write en la parte de imagen.Write(destino) y el "destino" es un Path con la dirección de la carpeta donde se va a guardar.